# AngularJS filter - Ruby on Rails assets:precompile issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, angularjs

I used AngularJS in Ruby on Rails. I used the currency filter with custom symbol.

```
<span>{{value|currency:'¥'}}<span>
```

The filter works fine in development enviroment.

```
¥1,000.00
```

However, when running in production mode, the currency symbol is converted to special character.

```
�1,000.00
```

PS: I've used UTF-8 encoding in all files. Tried the following in production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Sprockets::LazyCompressor.new { Uglifier.new(:mangle => false) }
```

Any idea how to solve the issue? Thanks folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a hack to fix the issue by overriding the currency filter and adding `.replace(/\uFFFD/g, currencySymbol);`

Original code below extracted from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1c1cd4fdf6b6d7511c7b8dc61b8042011dc54830/src/ng/filter/filters.js

```
currencyFilter.$inject = ['$locale'];
function currencyFilter($locale) {
  var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
  return function(amount, currencySymbol){
    if (isUndefined(currencySymbol)) currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
    return formatNumber(amount, formats.PATTERNS[1], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP, 2)
           .replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol);
  };
}
```

The final code will looks like the following

```
return formatNumber(amount,currencyFormat , ',', '.', fractionSize).
        replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol).replace(/\uFFFD/g, currencySymbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about including something like this in your `production.rb` environment file? 
`config.assets.precompile += %w( angular.js )`

or possible use this gem https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails